# Evaluating a tic-tac-toe board using a C-style for loop in Rust

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe, rust

I program in C, and it's my favourite language. I've recently found Rust. I like their ideas. Sometimes looks like a weird mixture of C++ and Haskell, but overall it looks nice.

The `for` loop in C is very flexible, and I truly miss them in Rust. Just look at my messy beginner Rust code below. Below that there is the equivalent C version, which (hopefully) doesn't look 'that' bad. I put the C version because I know my Rust code is unreadable; you need to look at C to understand why I wrote that mess. Tell me how to make my Rust code better. It doesn't have to copy all the C patterns, but there really needs to be something to compensate the lack of the flexible `for` loop.

If you're interested in what the whatever my code does. It determines the result of a tic-tac-toe board.

```
#![feature(libc)]

extern crate libc;

const SIZE: usize = 3;
const SIZE_2: usize = SIZE * SIZE;

fn determine_result(board: &[i32; SIZE_2]) -> i32 {
  'out: loop {
    let mut i = 0;
    'a: while i < SIZE_2 {
      if board[i] == 0 {
        i += SIZE;
        continue;
      }
      for j in i + 1 .. i + SIZE {
        if board[i] != board[j] {
          i += SIZE;
          continue 'a;
        }
      }
      return board[i];
    }
    'b: for i in 0 .. SIZE {
      if board[i] == 0 {
        continue;
      }
      let mut j = i + SIZE;
      while j < i + SIZE_2 {
        if board[i] != board[j] {
          continue 'b;
        }
        j += SIZE;
      }
      return board[i];
    }
    i = SIZE + 1;
    while i < SIZE_2 {
      if board[i] != board[0] {
        break 'out;
      }
      i += SIZE + 1;
    }
    return board[0];
  }
  let mut i = SIZE * 2 - 2;
  while i <= SIZE_2 - SIZE {
    if board[i] != board[SIZE - 1] {
      return 0;
    }
    i += SIZE - 1;
  }
  return board[SIZE - 1];
}

const N: usize = 50000000;

fn main() {
  unsafe {
    libc::srand(0);
  }
  let mut n = 0 as usize;
  let mut board: [i32; SIZE_2] = [0; SIZE_2];
  for i in 0 .. N {
    for i in 0 .. SIZE_2 {
      unsafe {
        board[i] = libc::rand() as i32 % 3;
      }
    }
    n += determine_result(&board) as usize;
  }
  println!("{}", n);
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3
#define SIZE_2 (SIZE * SIZE)

static int determineResult(int board[static SIZE_2]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_2; i += SIZE) {
    if (!board[i]) {
      continue;
    }
    for (int j = i + 1; j < i + SIZE; ++j) {
      if (board[i] != board[j]) {
        goto next;
      }
    }
    return board[i];
  next:;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    if (!board[i]) {
      continue;
    }
    for (int j = i + SIZE; j < i + SIZE_2; j += SIZE) {
      if (board[i] != board[j]) {
        goto next2;
      }
    }
    return board[i];
  next2:;
  }
  for (int i = SIZE + 1; i < SIZE_2; i += SIZE + 1) {
    if (board[i] != *board) {
      goto next3;
    }
  }
  return *board;
next3:
  for (int i = SIZE * 2 - 2; i <= SIZE_2 - SIZE; i += SIZE - 1) {
    if (board[i] != board[SIZE - 1]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return board[SIZE - 1];
}

#define N 100000000

int main(void) {
  srand(0);
  size_t n = 0;
  for (long i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    int board[SIZE_2];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_2; ++i) {
      board[i] = rand() % 3;
    }
    n += determineResult(board);
  }
  printf("%zu\n", n);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more how the score of a board is calculated?

Comment: The for loop as it exists in C isn't in Rust because it's designers (Mozilla research) didn't intend it to be! One of the largest issues most people seem to have when learning their second language, is letting go of the ideas they learned from the first. Each language has it's own style and philosophy to teach you to approach problems in new ways that you might not have thought of before, a skill arguably more important than actually knowing the language. Some people actually learn obscure languages just for the purpose of learning a new style of programming, rather than the language itself.

Comment: Side notes: 1) try and avoid goto's in your C code and 2) I'd suggest editing your question to be more focused around having the code reviewed, because as it stands your title (and most of your question) is asking for a solution to code you haven't written yet (a C-style for loop alternative in Rust), which is grounds for a moderator to remove the question (such a question would be better suited at Stack Overflow). 3) If your code is so unreadable (I wouldn't know; I don't use Rust), why not add coments to make it more readable?

Comment: @psychedelic_alex you can rather suggest me your own cleaner version without goto.

Comment: I could but Shepmaster has already offered a good explanation of what to do better in C

Comment: I'd also highly recommend opening a second question asking for code review of your C version! That's more-than-allowed here on CR, and might spread some ideas of doing it differently that will translate to different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version:

```rust
#![feature(libc)]

extern crate libc;

use std::fmt::{Display, Error, Formatter};
use Token::*;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Token {
    Empty,
    X,
    O,
}

impl Display for Token {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
        match *self {
            Empty => fmt.write_str("."),
            X => fmt.write_str("X"),
            O => fmt.write_str("O"),
        }
    }
}


const SIZE: usize = 3;

struct TicTacToe {
    board: [[Token; SIZE]; SIZE],
}

impl TicTacToe {
    fn determine_result(&self) -> Token {
    'rows_loop:
        for i in 0..SIZE {
            if self.board[i][0] == Token::Empty {
                continue;
            }

            for j in 1..SIZE {
                if self.board[i][0] != self.board[i][j] {
                    continue 'rows_loop;
                }
            }

            return self.board[i][0];
        }

    'columns_loop:
        for i in 0..SIZE {
            if self.board[0][i] == Token::Empty {
                continue;
            }

            for j in 1..SIZE {
                if self.board[0][i] != self.board[j][i] {
                    continue 'columns_loop;
                }
            }

            return self.board[0][i];
        }

    'nw_se_diagonal:
        loop {
            for i in 1..SIZE {
                if self.board[0][0] != self.board[i][i] {
                    break 'nw_se_diagonal;
                }
            }

            return self.board[0][0];
        }

        for i in 1..SIZE {
            if self.board[0][SIZE - 1] != self.board[i][SIZE - i - 1] {
                return Token::Empty;
            }
        }

        self.board[0][SIZE - 1]
    }
}

impl Display for TicTacToe {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
        for i in 0..SIZE {
            for j in 0..SIZE {
                try!(fmt.write_fmt(format_args!("{}", self.board[i][j])));
            }

            try!(fmt.write_str("\n"));
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

const TOKENS: [Token; 3] = [Empty, X, O];
fn random_token() -> Token {
    TOKENS[unsafe { libc::rand() } as usize % 3]
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        libc::srand(0);
    }
    for _ in 0..100 {
        let board = TicTacToe {
            board: [
                [random_token(), random_token(), random_token()],
                [random_token(), random_token(), random_token()],
                [random_token(), random_token(), random_token()],
            ],
        };
        print!("{}", board);
        println!("winner: {:?}", board.determine_result());
    }
}
```

The main change here is that I used a two-dimensional array (`[[Token; SIZE]; SIZE]`) rather than a flat array. This makes the code much more readable, because we don't have to calculate the index given a row and a column; the compiler does it for us. Thanks to this, I was able to use standard Rust `for` loops using only ranges that step by 1.

I also added the `Token` and `TicTacToe` types to make the intent of the code clearer. The `Display` implementations are only provided for `main` to be able to pretty print the board.

If you're not aware, there is a [`rand` crate on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/rand) that provides a safe API to a random number generator.

**EDIT:**

Here is another implementation in functional style (while still being careful to keep it as efficient as the original, if optimizations are enabled). Notice how the loop labels are no longer necessary.

```rust
impl TicTacToe {
    fn determine_result(&self) -> Token {
        if let Some(v) = (0..SIZE)
            .filter(|&i| self.board[i][0] != Token::Empty &&
                         (1..SIZE).all(|j| self.board[i][0] == self.board[i][j]))
            .map(|i| self.board[i][0])
            .next() {
            return v;
        }

        if let Some(v) = (0..SIZE)
            .filter(|&i| self.board[0][i] != Token::Empty &&
                         (1..SIZE).all(|j| self.board[0][i] == self.board[j][i]))
            .map(|i| self.board[0][i])
            .next() {
            return v;
        }

        if (1..SIZE).all(|i| self.board[0][0] == self.board[i][i]) {
            return self.board[0][0];
        }

        if (1..SIZE).all(|i| self.board[0][SIZE - 1] == self.board[i][SIZE - i - 1]) {
            return self.board[0][SIZE - 1];
        }

        Token::Empty
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is the only one that compiles directly. Also, I know I could've used a 2D array for both of my codes, and they often lead to better looking code, I agree. But I tend to avoid them when possible because I've seen the compiler getting confused and not optimizing the loop index calculation correctly. Sometimes the multiplications for 2D or n-D indexing just stays there and gives me not the expected result.

Comment: If you paste my code on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) and press the ASM or LLVM IR buttons, you can see what the Rust code is compiled into. ASM is of course assembler/machine code, and LLVM IR is an intermediate language that is then transformed to ASM (the LLVM IR output is generally shorter and easier to read, but it's not always low-level enough). Be sure to enable Release mode first to get optimized code!

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to start with the tough love... both your C and Rust code are unreadable. Nested loops with `goto` statements is the definition of *spaghetti code*, and that tends to be the least understandable and unmaintainable type of code. The good news is that you are here, asking for feedback, which is the right direction! ^_^

I'm going to mark suggestions with **[universal]** if they are just general programming ideas, not specific to Rust.

1. Rust uses a 4 space indent, not 2.
2. Ranges don't have spaces. Use `0..20` instead of `0 .. 20`.
3. Don't use the libc crate for random numbers, use the dedicated rand crate. This allows you to not need any `unsafe` code.
4. **[universal]** Always use a random number function for ranges. You should *not* use the modulus operator `%` as it can introduce sampling bias, preventing you from having a uniform distribution. In Rust, you can use `gen_range`.
5. Use `_` when you want to ignore unused variables, like the index value of a loop:

   ```
   for _ in 0..10 { }
   ```
6. **[universal]** Program-wide constants like `N` are terrible names. Give them better names that convey meaning and usage:

   ```
   const BENCHMARK_ITERATIONS: usize = 50000000;

   const SIZE_OF_ROW: usize = 3;
   const SIZE_OF_BOARD: usize = SIZE_OF_ROW * SIZE_OF_ROW;
   ```
7. Don't specify the type of a variable when it can be inferred:

   ```
   let mut board = [0; SIZE_2]; // no `: [i32; SIZE2] on the left

   n += determine_result(&board); // no `as usize`
   ```
8. Use iterators instead of manually incrementing an array index. This has improved performance, and prevents you from duplicating the length variable everywhere:

   ```
   for space in board.iter_mut() {
       *space = 0;
   ```
9. **[universal]** Declare variables with the minimal scope needed to do the job. For example, your `board` is only used inside the loop:

   ```
   for i in 0..10 {
       let mut board = [0; SIZE_2];
   ```
10. Use iterator adapters, like `map` or `fold`, instead of doing all the work yourself. These have higher semantic meaning, allowing other programmers to instantly know you are transforming a sequence or reducing it down to a single value. It also allows your code to avoid some mutability.
11. **[universal]** Extract out functions, such as one to generate a board. This allows the mutability of the board to be constrained to a very small area.
12. I'd create a newtype for `Board`, or at the very least a type alias. This allows you to have higher concepts as opposed to just an array.
13. There's no need for explicit `return` statements at the end of a function.
14. **[universal]** Extract out **more** functions. `determine_result` has too much going on in it, and breaking them out into functions makes the code way easier to reason about. Functions for "row winners" or "column winners" are identifiable.
15. **[universal]** There's no reason to use an `i32` for 3 values, that's massive overkill.
16. The absence of a value isn't really just another value, and you should use `Option` instead.

All together now:

**src/main.rs**

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate itertools;

use rand::{StdRng, Rng, SeedableRng};
use itertools::Itertools;

const SIZE_OF_ROW: usize = 3;
const SIZE_OF_BOARD: usize = SIZE_OF_ROW * SIZE_OF_ROW;

type Board = [Option<Piece>; SIZE_OF_BOARD];

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
enum Piece {
    X,
    O,
}

// If every item in an iterator is the same, that value is
// returned. If there are no items or not all items are equal, returns
// None.
fn all_the_same<I>(mut iter: I) -> Option<I::Item>
    where I: Iterator,
          I::Item: PartialEq + ::std::fmt::Debug
{
    let initial_value = match iter.next() {
        Some(v) => v,
        None => return None,
    };

    while let Some(value) = iter.next() {
        if initial_value != value {
            return None
        }
    }

    Some(initial_value)
}

fn flatten<T>(opt: Option<Option<T>>) -> Option<T> {
    match opt {
        Some(inner) => inner,
        None => None,
    }
}

fn column_winner(board: &Board) -> Option<Piece> {
    (0..3).filter_map(|col| {
        flatten(all_the_same(board.iter().skip(col).step(3)).cloned())
    }).next()
}

fn row_winner(board: &Board) -> Option<Piece> {
    board.chunks(3).filter_map(|row| {
        flatten(all_the_same(row.iter()).cloned())
    }).next()
}

fn top_left_diagonal_winner(board: &Board) -> Option<Piece> {
    flatten(all_the_same(board.iter().step(4)).cloned())
}

fn top_right_diagonal_winner(board: &Board) -> Option<Piece> {
    flatten(all_the_same(board[2..7].iter().step(2)).cloned())
}

fn determine_result(board: &Board) -> Option<Piece> {
    column_winner(board)
        .or_else(|| row_winner(board))
        .or_else(|| top_left_diagonal_winner(board))
        .or_else(|| top_right_diagonal_winner(board))
}

const BENCHMARK_ITERATIONS: usize = 50000000;

fn generate_board<R>(mut rng: R) -> Board
    where R: Rng
{
    let mut board = [None; SIZE_OF_BOARD];
    for space in board.iter_mut() {
        *space = match rng.gen_range(0, 3) {
            1 => Some(Piece::X),
            2 => Some(Piece::O),
            _ => None,
        };
    }
    board
}

fn main() {
    let mut rng = StdRng::from_seed(&[0]);

    let total =
        (0..BENCHMARK_ITERATIONS)
        .map(|_| generate_board(&mut rng))
        .map(|board| determine_result(&board))
        .map(|winner| {
            match winner {
                Some(Piece::X) => 1,
                Some(Piece::O) => 2,
                None => 0,
            }
        })
        .fold(0, |acc, val| acc + val);

    println!("{}", total);
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "tictactoe"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["A. Developer <a.developer@example.com>"]

[dependencies]
rand = "*"
itertools = "*"
```

Comment: I like your advice for rust, and that was my question. But don't call also my C code spaguetti. Just show me if you want to that I'm writing bad C, by your better C.

Comment: Also I cannot get your code compile.. no itertools crate?

Comment: @xiver77 note that I included a `Cargo.toml` that adds dependencies for the two crates I am suggesting you use. Leveraging reusable third-party components is a good idea in any language, but Rust has a leg up on C here as package management is baked into the language from 1.0.

Comment: @Shepmaster, Can you clarify the reasoning behind the match in `flatten<T>`? Specifically, why is there a need for a specific case `Some(None) => None`. Wouldn't `Some(other) => other` work the same?

Comment: @Kroltan nice catch! You are absolutely right. I think I started to write out all the explicit cases, realized that they were the same, then only cleaned up some of them.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `#![feature(libc)]`; use `libc` from crates.io:

```
[dependencies]
libc = "0.1"
```

This works on stable.

But then don't use `libc` at all - you should use Rust's `rand` crate.

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.3"
```

```
board[i] = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 3);
```

Because you're running this a ton, you'll want a faster version (at the expense of quality randomness), so something more like

```
let mut rng = rand::weak_rng();
let dist = Range::new(0, 3);
```

```
board[i] = dist.ind_sample(&mut rng);
```

Since you're using `const SIZE` and `const SIZE_2`, you should just consider a `[[i32; SIZE]; SIZE]`. This is flat in memory but much easier to use.

Before I do that, though, let's consider some nicer ways to write `determine_result`.

Firstly, your `'out loop` is disingenous. You never intend to loop in it. You use it here:

```
i = SIZE + 1;
while i < SIZE_2 {
  if board[i] != board[0] {
    break 'out;
  }
  i += SIZE + 1;
}
return board[0];
// 'out ends
```

This is nicer as

```
if (1..SIZE).all(|i| board[i + i * SIZE] == board[0]) {
    return board[0];
}
```

Then you need no fake outer loop at all.

You can do this all over:

```
fn determine_result(board: &[i32; SIZE_2]) -> i32 {
    for row in 0..SIZE {
        if board[row * SIZE] != 0 &&
                (1..SIZE).all(|col| board[row * SIZE] == board[col + row * SIZE]) {
            return board[row * SIZE];
        }
    }

    for col in 0..SIZE {
        if board[col] != 0 &&
                (1..SIZE).all(|row| board[col] == board[col + row * SIZE]) {
            return board[col];
        }
    }

    if (1..SIZE).all(|i| board[i + i * SIZE] == board[0]) {
            return board[0];
    }

    if (1..SIZE).all(|i| board[i + (SIZE - i - 1) * SIZE] == board[SIZE - 1]) {
            return board[SIZE - 1]
    }

    0
}
```

This has a lot of duplication, so let's make another function:

```
fn all_same<I>(board: &[i32; SIZE_2], row_cols: I) -> Option<i32>
    where I: Iterator<Item=(usize, usize)>
{
    let mut values = row_cols.map(|(row, col)| board[col + row * SIZE]);

    let first = values.next();
    match first {
        None | Some(0) => None,
        Some(fst) =>
            if values.all(|v| v == fst) { Some(fst) } else { None }
    }
}
```

and then we just need the more direct

```
fn determine_result(board: &[i32; SIZE_2]) -> i32 {
    for row in 0..SIZE {
        if let Some(val) = all_same(board, (1..SIZE).map(|col| (row, col))) {
            return val;
        }
    }

    for col in 0..SIZE {
        if let Some(val) = all_same(board, (1..SIZE).map(|row| (row, col))) {
            return val;
        }
    }

    if let Some(val) = all_same(board, (1..SIZE).map(|i| (i, i))) {
            return val;
    }

    if let Some(val) = all_same(board, (1..SIZE).map(|i| (i, SIZE - i - 1))) {
            return val;
    }

    0
}
```

This is all well and good, but we should really be doing better. Let's go to `&[[i8; SIZE]; SIZE]`. Because of the abstraction gained, we only really need to change

```
let mut values = row_cols.map(|(row, col)| board[row][col]);
```

Now, personally I'd be much more tempted to use

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Tile {
    Empty,
    Player1,
    Player2
}
```

You'll want this:

```
impl Rand for Tile {
    fn rand<R: Rng>(rng: &mut R) -> Tile {
        match rng.gen::<u8>() {
            0...84 => return Tile::Empty,
            85...169 => return Tile::Player1,
            170...254 => return Tile::Player2,
            _ => rng.gen()
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the rest falls into place. Because we're doing

```
board[i][j] = rng.gen();
```

now, you can actually just do

```
board = rng.gen();
```

Note that `0 as usize` should just be `0usize`. Further, `usize` is a strange type to use; prefer explicit types like `u64`.

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::{Rand, Rng};

const SIZE: usize = 3;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Tile {
    Empty,
    Player1,
    Player2
}

impl Rand for Tile {
    fn rand<R: Rng>(rng: &mut R) -> Tile {
        match rng.gen::<u8>() {
            0...84 => return Tile::Empty,
            85...169 => return Tile::Player1,
            170...254 => return Tile::Player2,
            _ => rng.gen()
        }
    }
}

fn all_same<I>(board: &[[Tile; SIZE]; SIZE], row_cols: I) -> Tile
    where I: Iterator<Item=(usize, usize)>
{
    let mut values = row_cols.map(|(row, col)| board[row][col]);

    let first = values.next().unwrap_or(Tile::Empty);
    match first {
        Tile::Empty => Tile::Empty,
        fst => if values.all(|v| v == fst) { fst } else { Tile::Empty }
    }
}

fn determine_result(board: &[[Tile; SIZE]; SIZE]) -> Tile {
    for row in 0..SIZE {
        let tile = all_same(board, (1..SIZE).map(|col| (row, col)));
        if tile != Tile::Empty { return tile; }
    }

    for col in 0..SIZE {
        let tile = all_same(board, (1..SIZE).map(|row| (row, col)));
        if tile != Tile::Empty { return tile; }
    }

    let tile = all_same(board, (1..SIZE).map(|i| (i, i)));
    if tile != Tile::Empty { return tile; }

    let tile = all_same(board, (1..SIZE).map(|i| (i, SIZE - i - 1)));
    if tile != Tile::Empty { return tile; }

    Tile::Empty
}

const N: usize = 50000000;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::weak_rng();

    let mut n = 0u64;
    for _ in 0 .. N {
        n += match determine_result(&rng.gen()) {
            Tile::Empty => 0,
            Tile::Player1 => 1,
            Tile::Player2 => 2,
        };
    }
    println!("{}", n);
}
```

Comment: How do I fix error: unresolved name `rand::weak_rng`?

Comment: Are you using `cargo` with `[dependencies]\nrand = "0.3"` in your `Cargo.toml`? If not, I suggest very strongly that you do.

Comment: I'll look into `cargo`, but is it also possible to link directly from command line with rustc? I just prefer writing short shell scripts for small programs, rather than external build tools..

Comment: @xiver77 Probably, but *everyone* uses `cargo`. It's easy: `cargo new foldername --bin`; `cd foldername`; `echo '\n[dependencies]\nrand = "0.3"' >> Cargo.toml`; `file-editor src/main.rs`; `cargo run --release`. You probably also have `cargo` installed, since it typically comes with Rust.

Answer (score 0):

So, your C. Many of the points from the other reviews hold for C, too, but C doesn't easily allow the cool abstractions we were talking about. So here are some lighter abstractions that actually work quite nicely. In some ways I'll be taking this further than with Rust, and in other ways less far.

The main challenge is again in `determineResult`. The use of `goto` really isn't very nice; traditionally one woiuld try to avoid this with functions. So let's aim for a similar functionality to the `all_same` I used with Rust:

```
static int idx(int row, int col) {
    return row * SIZE + col;
}

static int getRowSame(int board[static SIZE_2], int start, int step, int count) {
    int first = board[start];
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        if (board[start + i * step] != first) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

This allows you to do just

```
static int determineResult(int board[static SIZE_2]) {
    int val;

    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        if ((val = getRowSame(board, idx(row, 0), idx(0, 1), SIZE)) != 0) {
            return val;
        }
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
        if ((val = getRowSame(board, idx(0, col), idx(1, 0), SIZE)) != 0) {
            return val;
        }
    }
    if ((val = getRowSame(board, idx(0, 0), idx(1, 1), SIZE)) != 0) {
        return val;
    }
    if ((val = getRowSame(board, idx(0, SIZE-1), idx(1, -1), SIZE)) != 0) {
        return val;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

for the main loop.

I would also consider using an enum for clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3
#define SIZE_2 (SIZE * SIZE)

typedef enum {
    EMPTY = 0,
    PLAYER_1 = 1,
    PLAYER_2 = 2
} tile;

static int idx(int row, int col) {
    return row * SIZE + col;
}

static tile getRowSame(tile board[static SIZE_2], int start, int step, int count) {
    tile first = board[start];
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        if (board[start + i * step] != first) {
            return EMPTY;
        }
    }
    return first;
}

static tile determineResult(tile board[static SIZE_2]) {
    int val;

    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        if ((val = getRowSame(board, idx(row, 0), idx(0, 1), SIZE)) != EMPTY) {
            return val;
        }
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
        if ((val = getRowSame(board, idx(0, col), idx(1, 0), SIZE)) != EMPTY) {
            return val;
        }
    }
    if ((val = getRowSame(board, idx(0, 0), idx(1, 1), SIZE)) != EMPTY) {
        return val;
    }
    if ((val = getRowSame(board, idx(0, SIZE-1), idx(1, -1), SIZE)) != EMPTY) {
        return val;
    }

    return EMPTY;
}

#define N 100000000

int main(void) {
    srand(0);
    size_t n = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        tile board[SIZE_2];
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_2; ++i) {
            board[i] = rand() % 3;
        }
        n += determineResult(board);
    }
    printf("%zu\n", n);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: While I believe there is no reason to dislike `goto`, I truly like your code. You removed all the duplications with  a very clever function. The `count` parameter in `getRowSame` is probably unnecessary, though, because you know it will be `SIZE`.

Comment: @xiver77 The dislike for `goto` would disappear if people would stop using it where they ought not ;). I found your control flow extremely confusing, since there were so many control flow constructs and `goto` went through the middle of them (often in different ways).

Comment: Yes you did it much better. But the use of goto in my code was consistent: to break the outer loop. That's why it was possible your you to capture out the pattern and build a clever function.

Comment: @xiver Adding to Veedrac's point, the best way to use `goto` is for unified failure handling of a single function. Things like deallocating memory or closing files. There's only a single `error:` label at the end that does all the cleanup. In this case, `goto` is used to emulate exceptions (or Go's `defer`) and truly does make the code cleaner.